# CSS - Set element's max-width as a multiple of min-content

Tags: html, css, max

TLDR; I can set the `max-width` of an element to `min-content`, but I how can I set it to `min-content * n`?

---

I have an element with dynamically determined content inside a container. The page is viewed on a wide viewport (viewport width > table's `min-width`). Something like this:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="data"><!-- Some content here --></div>
</section>
```

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: stretch;
}
.data {
  min-width: min-content;
}
```

I would like the div to stretch in width, but only to an extent. Again, the content of the div is dynamically determined, so I cannot set a fixed value for `max-width`. Therefore I would like to set its `max-width` to be a multiple of its `min-width`, something like this:

```
.data {
  min-width: min-content;
  max-width: calc(min-content * 1.5);
}
```

---

Obviously I cannot do this because `min-content` is a named property value, not a resolvable number. So how should I achieve this in CSS only? Or am I obliged to use JS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `justify-content: stretch;` Will make the table always fill the container, if you want space between cells use depending on the viewport use `border-spacing` with viewport units `border-spacing:2vw;`

Comment: @ZohirSalak `justify-content: stretch;` will respect table's `max-width`. `border-spacing` is not what I want. I want each cell to expand, as is the default behaviour - not to have gaps between them. There is a difference.

Comment: @ZohirSalak https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#Values

Comment: Are you trying to have space between table cells or grid items ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. For me it does not matter what the thing inside the container is, whether it's a `div` or `table`. For a table, that means each cell expands individually, but it really doesn't matter because that's the default behaviour. I simply want to set a cap on how far this element can expand using `max-width`, and I would like this value to be determined dynamically, because the content itself is dynamic.

Comment: The container always have the width of the viewport, and contains only this one element. It is there for the sole reason of centering the internal element.

Comment: Okay so you want a dynamic cap on the parent determined by it's content. This is clearly not possible just with CSS Alone. a container can't know how big it's content is. even with JS is a headache to manage, What if there's a huge image that takes ages to load.

Comment: Not exactly. I want a dynamic cap on size of the **content** determined by **itself**. Again, something like this: `.data { min-width: min-content; max-width: calc(min-content * 1.5); }`

Comment: It's not determined by *itself*, You're setting the cap on the parent of that content, so it's the parent who should know how big it is exactly so you can make calculations on it.

Comment: I don't understand. How am I setting a cap on the parent? It's completely okay to only have `<div class="data"></div>` and `.data { min-width: min-content; max-width: calc(min-content * 1.5); }` without enclosing it in something else, isn't it?

Comment: The parent refers to `.data`

Comment: Ah right. I'm getting you now. Makes sense that while `div` can delegate its content to determine its size with `min-content`, it cannot obtain its content`s size directly. If you can put your explanation down as an answer I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks.